# How to pass string in url params?

Tags: angular

From API I get something like this : `processId=22`, now i want to pass that in url params, but problem is that i need to pass key and value. How can i paste that whole string as param. Any suggestion?

So what i want to achive is this:

```
<a *ngIf="menu.refParameter3" [routerLink]="[menu.url ||'/']" [queryParams]="{menu.refParameter3}">test</a>
```

So in `menu.refParamter3` i have `processId=22`. How can i paste both in url, so that i can have `something.com?processId=22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to pass in the key + value string as query parameters. Once you receive the parameter from the api, you could convert it to an object and pass it in to the `queryParams` input.

```
// basic conversion code
let queryParams = {};
let split = menu.refParameter3.split('=');
queryParams[split[0]] = split[1];
menu.queryParams = queryParams;

// menu.queryParams = {
//     processId: 22
// }

// html
<a [routerLink]="[menu.url ||'/']" [queryParams]="menu.queryParams">test</a>
```

Comment: thats fixed value processId:22 i want to avoid that and get  key and value from api and pass it to query params

Comment: you can make it dynamic based on how your code is set up. Once you receive the key value from the api convert it from a string to the above format

Comment: @None I've updated my answer with some basic code that would convert the string to an object

Comment: problem is that queryParams not add in url this object processId: "22"

Comment: What url do you get?

Comment: i dont get anything in url...but if i do console log i get this :queryParams:
processId:"22"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158708/discussion-between-llai-and-none).